# Firebase Invites on iOS - how to get invite from universal link?

Tags: firebase, firebase-invites

I'm walking through the Firebase Invite setup to send and receive invites in my iOS app. However, it seems like the Invites function they use to retrieve an invite from a URL, `Invites.handleUniversalLink(url)`, [is no longer available.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pK2Xd.png)

I get an error saying *Type 'Invites' has no member 'handleUniversalLink'.*

Any ideas why I'm getting this error? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Are you perhaps using the wrong `Invites`, from another library? Can you check?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion–the issue was resolved when I updated Xcode. Sorry I forgot to resolve this question!

Comment: No worries, glad you sorted it! I probably wouldn't have commented if I had noticed the question was 7 weeks old!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved when I updated to the latest version of Xcode.